# Hyper-V - No Guest Internet

Tags: windows, azure, hyper-v, hypervisor, windows-server-2019

I'm using a Windows Server 2019 server from Microsoft Azure. I have installed Hyper-V with the management tools and am now trying to setup a Ubuntu 14.04LTS VM inside of Hyper-V. I create a new External Switch however when setting up the Ubuntu instance there it tells me that there is an issue with the DHCP server. When I check my network connections for the newly created switch there is IPV4 connectivity, with packets being sent and received.

Things that I have tried:

-Ensured that inside of the Virtual Switch Manager that in my newly created virtual switch, the external network is selected as my main internet adapter. And that the "Allow management os to share this network adapter".

-Tried selecting "Internal Network"

-Inside of the ubuntu server, tried dchlient -r and dhclient eth0 to try to retrieve a new IP (For internal network this has worked, but without internet access, for external ip it hangs on the command dhclient eth0)

-In Network Connections I have tried bridging the two connections (out of desperation, "bricks" the vps causing me to not be able to rdp, must create a new azure vm)

-I have tried right clicking the main "ethernet" inside the Network Connections and allowing sharing options to other users.

Please help as I'm quite lost as to why the Ubuntu Guest is not connecting to the internet with the new network switch

Answer (score 1):

The virtual switch connection types are very confusingly named, and sharing is somewhat flaky. I've had best results with the Internal Network. Most of the time it just works but there are certain situations when the NAT service breaks and you will have to restart some combination of the host and guest machines, possibly both -- I've not found a way to just restart the virtual switch service without restarting the host OS.

If you need to use the External Network type, be aware that your actual physical router will be in the mix, so you must make sure that it is properly configured, especially if you're doing MAC filtering on your router and the guest is not using the hardware MAC. This usually happens because of the virtualisation process itself, even if it's not something you've configured in the guest.